# C# Хочу спрятать стеганографически информацию в кадрах видео(mp4) методом младших битов(lsb)

Tags: c#, видео, стеганография, aforge

Друзья может кто шарит, помогите пожалуйста, делаю на C#. Использовал для этого библиотеку Aforge .Net
В картинки прячу и достаю без проблем, но вот с видео беда. 
Пример(пишу по памяти, так как не за компом, но смысл уловите):

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap() ;
Bitmap stegimg  = new Bitmap() ;

VideoFileReader videofileread = new VideoFileReader();
videofile.Open(@"D:\video.mp4");
VideoFileWriter videofilewrite = new VideoFileWriter();
writer.Open( "test.mp4", video file.width, videofile.height, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4 );

// write 1000 video frames
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
   img = videofile.NextFrame();
   stegimg = StegSecretWriter(img); //пример функции которая прячет информацию в пиксели кадра
   videofilewriter.WriteVideoFrame( image );
}
videofilereader.Close( );
videofilewriter.Close();
```

И вот на выходе видео (test.mp4) очень сильно жмётся, качество ужасное.

Соответственно, достать информацию из пикселей в кадрах не представляется возможным. Так как сжатие изменяет даже оттенки их цветов, а метод `lsb`, как раз на этом завязан. 
Подскажите как поступить, или может в крайнем случае как нибудь прятать в Metadata файла, в общем, чтобы после воссоздания файла из кадров, в итоге можно было безболезненно извлечь информацию.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте спрятать информацию в JPEG, разобравшись, как он устроен. Может, что-то станет понятнее. Если прятать в мета-данных, что проще, то может там есть строки, закодированные в utf-8, тогда можно использовать неоднозначность кодирования.

Comment: То есть формат mp4 это ряд изображений jpeg, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Нет. Со сжатыми форматами (JPEG, MP4) LSB так просто использовать нельзя. Если только выставить очень высокое качество/битрейт. Я посоветовал попробовать проделать это с JPEG, чтобы стало понятно, во что это упирается.

Comment: Тогда вопрос, а вам не известно как выглядит формат jpeg сколько байт под заголовок и так далее, я пытался это найти, но как то безуспешно (может плохо искал)